# Titan standard indexing vs Elastic Search indexing

Tags: elasticsearch, titan

According to the Titan Wiki, the Titan standard index is only able to perform queries with exact matches,
and using elastic search will enable me to perform queries with numeric ranges and full-text searches.

However, when I perform the following WITHOUT elasticsearch:

```
g=TitanFactory.open('e:/titan-cassandra.properties');
v=g.addVertex(null);
v.setProperty('mytext','i am the first vertex.');
v.setProperty('age',123);
v=g.addVertex(null);
v.setProperty('mytext','hello from a vertex.');
v.setProperty('age',456);
v=g.addVertex(null);
v.setProperty('mytext','hello world.');
v.setProperty('age',789);
System.out.println();
g.V.map;
System.out.println();
g.V.has('mytext',Text.REGEX,'.*vertex.*').map;
System.out.println();
g.V.has('mytext',Text.REGEX,'.*hello.*').map;
System.out.println();
g.V.has('age',Cmp.GREATER_THAN_EQUAL,200).has('age',Cmp.LESS_THAN_EQUAL,700).map;
```

I am able to get the correct results as follows:

```
==>{mytext=i am the first vertex., age=123}
==>{mytext=hello from a vertex., age=456}
==>{mytext=hello world., age=789}

==>null
==>{mytext=hello from a vertex., age=456}
==>{mytext=i am the first vertex., age=123}

==>null
==>{mytext=hello world., age=789}
==>{mytext=hello from a vertex., age=456}

==>null
==>{mytext=hello from a vertex., age=456}
```

I am very curious. Why is this happening?
Do I still require elasticsearch to perform regular expression searches or numeric range searches?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

What you read in the wiki is correct.  Titan is only capable of using "standard indices" for exact matches.  Note what happens when I try this code in the Titan Console:

```
gremlin> g.V.has('mytext',Text.REGEX,'.*vertex.*').map;
WARN  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx  - Query requires iterating over all vertices [(mytext REGEX .*vertex.*)]. For better performance, use indexes
==>{mytext=i am the first vertex., age=123}
==>{mytext=hello from a vertex., age=456}
```

As you can see, no indices are being used (standard or otherwise). Titan simply does the regex evaluation in-memory.  Had you defined an ElasticSearch index on `mytext` Titan would have realized that and optimized the query to utilize that index and you wouldn't have seen that message.